# Javascript: Why can't object literal use assign?

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, Object has an `assign` function. Since an object literal has a `__proto__` of `Object.prototype`, why can't an object literal use `assign` and must go through Object directly?

`Object.assign({}, {hello: 'world'})`

```
const o = {};
o.assign({add: 'more stuff'})
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. your first piece of code works fine; it will assign the properties and values of the second object to the first object. You're not doing anything with the result, but it's doing what you ask it to...

Comment: Probably because assign is a static method from the Object class. Why would you want to tho anyway? You can always just say `o.add = 'more stuff';`

Comment: @IsaacVidrine I don't want to do it. Wrapping my head around inheritance in JS, thus I asked the question

Answer (score 3):

The Object prototype does not have the method `assign` on it.  Open the F12 console and type `Object.prototype` to see what is available on the base object prototype.

`Object.assign` is considered a static method, not an instance method.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `assign` is sort of a static function. It is not defined into the prototype.

Here is an example:

```js
function SomeClass(foo) {
  this.foo = foo;
}

// this is a method, it is attached to the prototype
SomeClass.prototype.showFoo = function() {
  console.log(this.foo);
}

// this is a static method, it is not attached to the prototype
SomeClass.bar = function() {
  console.log("bar");
}

var instance = new SomeClass("foo");

console.log(instance.showFoo);       // OK
console.log(instance.bar);           // not OK

console.log(SomeClass.showFoo);      // not OK
console.log(SomeClass.bar);          // OK
```

Comment: Not sort of, it is.

Comment: @IsaacVidrine a static function would require a `static` keyword. Javascript doesn't have static functions, it just mimics them.

Comment: Well using that logic, saying `var k = 1` means that the data type of  `k` isn't the actually `int`, it just mimics `int`

Comment: @IsaacVidrine Yes, `var k = 1` just mimics `int` because javascript is an untyped language. It only has one type for numeric values called `number`.

Comment: Thanks, learned something. Wasn't aware of the concept of "first class" objects.

Answer (score 0):

The `assign` function isn't in the prototype property of `Object` and just the properties and methods defined on it can be accessed by created objects, to prove that let's do this:

```
Object.prototype.assign = function(){}; // this create a function called assign in the prototype property of Object
var obj = {};
obj.assign(); // Now we can access the assign function with the object literal
```

Hope this help.